# Doctrine2 - multiple insert in one query

Tags: doctrine-orm, bulkinsert

I assumed doctrine2 would optimize my query to give the best performance for any database transactions.

I was inserting approximately 500 records in a database table, and i came to notice it created 500+ query to insert the records (one query per record), i am wondering, why wouldn't doctrine make use of multiple inserts to insert all record in one shot, wouldn't this reduce load and optimize the query? am i missing something about this behavior from doctrine?

Here is the code i am using for insertion:

```
$content = json_decode($response->getBody());
$em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
foreach ($content as $value) {
    $log = new log();
    $log->fromArray($value);
    $em->persist($log);
}
$em->flush();
```

**Update1:**
Here is the content of fromArray() as requested, the purpose of this function is to basically consolidate values to class property from an array:

```
/**
 * Map parameters with class property.
 *
 * @param $array array
 * @access public
 * @return $this
 */
public function fromArray(array $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $property => $value) {
        $method = 'set'.ucwords($property);
        $this->$method($value);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Here is content of `$content`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 111
        [guid] => aaaa-bbbb-cccc
        [wid] => 100
        [pid] => 101
        [start] => 2014-11-22T12:44:44+00:00
        [stop] => 2014-11-22T15:23:11+00:00
        [duration] => 9507
        [description] => Log description
        [tags] => Array
            (
                [0] => test
            )
        [at] => 2014-11-24T07:28:09+00:00
        [uid] => 51
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 112
        [guid] => dddd-eee
        [wid] => 100
        [pid] => 101
        [billable] => 
        [start] => 2014-11-22T15:35:07+00:00
        [stop] => 2014-11-22T15:45:21+00:00
        [duration] => 614
        [description] => Lorem description
        [tags] => Array
            (
                [0] => php
                [1] => pm
            )
        [at] => 2014-11-24T04:35:30+00:00
        [uid] => 51
    )
)
```

Comment: Doctrine doesn't handle your request in a magic way, it does whatever you ask it to. You persist in foreach(which is true as i see) and probably there are more records than 500.. You must solve that before sending data to persist method, i mean you must use a better denormalisation way

Comment: @İlhanÇetinm thank you for you reply, as i understand there is no magic here, isn't it the basic of query optimization? since this is the default method of insertion, it makes me wonder if Doctrine even allows bulk insertion?

Comment: @İlhanÇetin I am not sure if i am following you correctly, will appreciate if you can show some example.

Comment: can you please share the content of `fromArray()` and if possible an instance of `$value` in pastebin or a gist

Comment: I shall controll with my colleagues & return. Still nothing looks abnormal to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at [this](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html) document. At every iteration, Doctrine creates one `insert ...` query for you, after all, when you call `flush()`, Doctrine sends all those insert queries to db at one time inside a loop(using a mechanizm like `foreach(queries as query) { run->query.. }`)
In your case any of these queries are inserts, so, as i stated in comment, there is no abnormal situation in your case. ORM may not be suitable for all cases.

Comment: The question is, why does Doctrine creates one insert query per iteration, why does it not make use of multiple insert?

Comment: please take a look at the document i linked. The answer is given under a worning class to take attraction.